# Add timestamp column with default NOW() for new rows only

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that has thousands of rows. Since the table wasn't constructed with created_at column initially, there is no way of getting their creation timestamp. It is crucial though to start getting the timestamps for future rows.

Is there a way I can add a timestamp column with default value NOW() so that it won't populate the values to previous rows but only for the future ones?

If I do the `ALTER` query, it populates all rows with timestamp:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW()
```

Answer (score 269):

You need to add the column with a default of `null`, then alter the column to have default `now()`.

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN created_at TIMESTAMP;
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN created_at SET DEFAULT now();
```

Answer (score 75):

You could add the default rule with the alter table,

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW()
```

then immediately set to null all the current existing rows:

```
UPDATE mytable SET created_at = NULL
```

Then from this point on the `DEFAULT` will take effect.

Comment: It's good in principle, though it does carry the weight of doing an update which *may* fire triggers.

Comment: @Artur: The solution Philip presented is the way to go. `UPDATE` is not necessary. If you add a column default to an *existing* column, already existing rows are not affected. The default is only filled in if you add column and default in the same command.

Answer (score 45):

For example, I will create a table called `users` as below and give a column named `date` a default value `NOW()`

```sql
create table users_parent (
    user_id     varchar(50),
    full_name   varchar(240),
    login_id_1  varchar(50),
    date        timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
);
```

Thanks

Comment: This does not answer the original question at all. The question is about _altering_ an existing table, **not** creating a new table.

Answer (score 4):

minor optimization.

```
select pg_typeof(now());   --returns: timestamp with time zone. So now include timezone.
```

So better with timestamptz.

```
begin;
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN created_at TIMESTAMPTZ;
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN created_at SET DEFAULT now();
commit;
```

Comment: how to set default time that is not now but like zero time? so that way the column does not contain null value? and one can calculate time difference? what will that be? `now()` gives current time

Comment: ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN created_at SET DEFAULT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC';

Answer (score -2):

Try something like:-

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_table_name_Created] 
DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [created_at];
```

replacing `table_name` with the name of your table.

Comment: what is the benefit of such a CONTSTRAINT?