# Creating a default timestamp in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, datetime, time

I want to create default timestamp column in an existing table.

My first query is

`"ALTER TABLE {table_name} ADD COLUMN modifiedDate timestamp without time zone"`

This works and successfully adds the column.

However the second query

`ALTER TABLE {table_name} ALTER modifiedDate SET DEFAULT '2001-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone;`

fails to update all the rows on the column to contain that timestamp.

I was following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38916347) SO post.

I also tried in one query

`"ALTER TABLE {table_name} ADD COLUMN modifiedDate timestamp without time zone" SET DEFAULT '2001-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone;`

but that gave an error `syntax error at or near "00"`

Answer (score 1):

Silly mistake.

`ALTER TABLE {table_name} ADD COLUMN modifiedDate timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT '2001-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone;`

The `SET` should not be in the one liner.