# Created date, last modified date fields in postgress

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL, is there a way to add columns that will automatically record the creation date and latest updated date of a row?

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38916063/add-timestamp-column-with-default-now-for-new-rows-only) for an option for handling the creation date.  The latest update is another story.

Comment: Use column with DEFAULT now() for creation date, trigger BEFORE UPDATE FOR EACH ROW with NEW.upd_date = now(); RETURN NEW; for update date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- for table creation date look to [event triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/event-triggers.html)
- for insertion look into `DEFAULT` value for `timestamptz` column (works only if you don't explicitly define value)
- for last modification, use trigger `FOR EACH ROW` before `DELETE/UPDATE`

Answer (score 0):

The idea - Robust way of adding created and modified fields for data we add to database through db triggers

Update modified_by and modeified_on or modified_at for every db transaction.

Pick created_on and created_by or created_at from modified details whenever you insert a row into tables.

For trigger function, check this repo https://github.com/charan4ks/created_fields.git