# Dynamically replicate a table inside a postgresql database

Tags: postgresql

I have a table A (task, person) in a postgresql database.

I would like to create a live clone of it, table B (task, person, timestamp) which is synchronized with table A using now() as a value for timestamp column.

In other words when a record is written to table A, I would like it also to be written into table B with a timestamp of when it was written saved in the additional column.

Is that possible to do automatically using postgresql server functionality?

Comment: Use logical replication https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication.html

Comment: Why not just have table B, then make A a view onto it which doesn't show the timestamp column?

Comment: @jjanes – I would love to, but the table A is managed by the software I have installed. They are thinking of adding the extra column but I need it in the meantime.

Comment: What do you mean by "managed"?  Like, what operations do they do to the table that you can't control?  If they detect you changed something will they refuse to run, or drop and recreate it?

Answer (score 0):

If you rename "A" to "B", add a column to "B" with the correct default (`now()`, I assume), and then create a view named "A" which just selects all columns of "B" except the new column, then things should continue to work as before.  Inserts, updates, and deletes on "A" should automatically happen on "B" instead.

Note that only inserts will get the default value applied.  updates will not change the value from what was inserted (you could write a trigger to do that).  Is is not clear if that is what you want.

If your app tries to apply DDL (such as with migrations) to the table, that will probably go badly.  If it just does SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE, it should work fine.

Comment: The problem is, of course, that the app does schema and data migrations during upgrades. So ALTER is definitely going to happen sooner or later.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to just alter the existing table and add a column to it with a default set to now().
In order to avoid populating existing rows I did it following this advise:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38916347/14296314

I will just have to watch out for the migration process and deal with it when the time comes.

Thanks @jjanes